# SpringIntegration: Service-Activator not invoking method

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to read Message from a RabbitMQ Queue > Use Service-Activator to invoke a Service.

The relevant config section is:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fromRabbit"                                           queue-names="si.test.queue" mapped-request-headers="whatever" 
                                  connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="fromRabbit" output-channel="whatever"
               ref="msgService" method="checkMsg"/>

<bean id="msgService" class="com.whatever.MsgService"/>
```

The MsgService Class is:

```
public class MsgService{
//Does not work!
public void checkMsg( @Payload String s) {
    System.out.println("The Payload is: " +s);      
     }

}
```

But i get following error message:
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ***Target object of type [class org.springframework.integration.service.MessageExaminer] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.***

What am i doing wrong here?

But if i simply use this as a method in ServiceMsg class - that works:

```
public void seeMessage(String m)
    {
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```

My goal is to get hold of the Message itself, Payload and Headers in Service-Activator method.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get the message proper via SpEL, you can use

```
#root
```

an example would be

```
    <int:channel id="quick.channel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="quick.channel" 
        expression="@quickService.process(#root)"/>
```

this would allow you to access the message in your service

```
    public void process(Message<?> msg) {
        //do something with it
    }
```

Note: this makes your service code tightly coupled to Spring Integration - are you sure you want to do that? if you need a combination of things from the header and the payload, why not pass them in as separate arguments to the service, thereby decoupling the service from the Spring Integration message object?

like

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="quick.channel" 
expression="@quickService.process(headers['headerValue'],payload)"/>
```

and the service would be

```
public void process(String headerValue,Object payload) {
    //use them together
}
```